# How to stop npm start if a script build failed

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have some scripts in package.json. When I run npm start, dependencies are installed and scripts are run, However if any script fails the build process does not stop? I want to stop the build-process if any of the script loading fails. How do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by build process?

Comment: Could you post you package.json or at least your run config?

Comment: When I run npm start. It installs dependencies and runs scripts mentioned in package.json right? 
Let's say one of the script do not work due to any reason, what happens right now is that build process do not stop, it displays the error and it skips it and continues with the next script and website is made with wrong code. I want to avoid this. I hope I am clear